# How to make user-defined exceptions in python?

Tags: python, exception, user-defined-types

**I want to Raise Multiple User-Defined Exceptions**

For example -

- incase of an invalid parameter passed to function raise `ParameterException`
- incase of invalid something raise `CertainExceptions` and so on.

How can I do something like that in Python?

Comment: See [User Defined exceptions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html?highlight=exceptions#user-defined-exceptions) in the documentation.

Comment: Which part are you asking about? Raising (defining?) one custom exception? Raising one exception conditionally? Checking multiple conditions to trigger different effects?

Comment: Please be specific when you ask a question. See here if necessary : https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Consider the program below.

Program 1:

```
# this program would keep prompting the user for an integer input.
while True:
    a=int(input("Enter integer: "))
    b=int(input("Enter another integer: "))
    print(a/b)
```

Run the program and keep inputting. If everything is fine, it will print the division of the two integers. Now
Case 1: what if you input a random string?
Case 2: Or what if you input 0 at the place of b variable?

Feel free to test it. You would see that,
i) Case 1 raises ValueError exception
ii) Case 2 raises ZeroDivisionError exception

Now, you need to handle these exceptions. How can you do that? Here's how:

Program 2:

```
# this program handles ValueError and ZeroDivisionError exceptions
while True:
    try:
        a=int(input("Enter integer: "))
        b=int(input("Enter another integer: "))
        result=a/b
    except ValueError:
        print("Input is not integer.")
    except ZeroDivisionError:
        print("Division by 0 is not supported.")
    else:
        print(result)

    print("\n")
```

Besides, you can handle all exceptions like this:

Program 3:

```
while True:
    try:
        a=int(input("Enter integer: "))
        b=int(input("Enter another integer: "))
        result=a/b
    except Exception:
        print("An error occured.")
    else:
        print(result)

    print("\n")
```

In case of user-defined exceptions, do it like this:

```
class MyException(Exception):
    pass

while True:
    a=int(input("Enter integer: "))
    b=int(input("Enter another integer: "))
    if b==0:
        raise MyException

    print("\n")
```

Later catch them like you want.

Program 3 is not a good practice. Never pass errors silently. You can make use of python's Exception class by subclassing it.